# Windows Form with Resizing Frame and no Title Bar?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, resize, titlebar

How can I hide the title bar from a Windows Form but still have a Resizing Frame?

Comment: C#, Microsoft Visual Studio 2005

Comment: perfect answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39598230/5574962

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Setting FormBorderStyle = None will remove the title bar (at both design and
run time) - and also remove your ability to resize the form.

If you need a border you can set:

```
ControlBox = false
Text = ""
```

Comment: One side effect of this solution is that by setting Text="" for the form, you get no title in the Taskbar.

Comment: Another side effect is that the border is no longer themed.

Comment: You can get a themed-border by setting `FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizeableToolWindow;`

Answer (score 2):

Set the ControlBox property of the form to False, and the Text property to empty string. The form will open with no perceivable (to the user) title bar, but they will be able to resize the form.