# how to display an image without a window in C#

Tags: c#, image

I would like to know how to open an image without having a window open, so its like the the image is floating on my desktop with no border. thanks

Comment: This [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536141/how-to-draw-directly-on-the-windows-desktop-c) may help you.you need to draw the picture pixel by pixel using the same technic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do is to draw an image on the screen without a visible window border around it. Whether a window will be created is a totally different question. And as it turns out, you have to have a window. It just won't be visible. So:

Create a window, making sure to set the following in `InitializeComponent()`:

```
this.ControlBox = false;
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
this.MaximizeBox = false;
this.MinimizeBox = false;
this.ShowIcon = false;
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

Then, override `OnPaintBackground` for that window, as follows:

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground( WinForms.PaintEventArgs e )
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage( Image, 0, 0, Width, Height );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If all you want is a [splash screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen), there's a framework component for that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.splashscreen.aspx

Answer (score 3):

**Show a window without the title bar**

In case of winforms -

```
FormBorderStyle = None
ControlBox = false
```

taken from - [Windows Form with Resizing Frame and no Title Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93716/windows-form-with-resizing-frame-and-no-title-bar)

In case of XAML use this to show window without title bar -

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Width="640" Height="480" 
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">

    <!-- Content -->

</Window>
```

taken from - [Is it possible to display a wpf window without an icon in the title bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553715/is-it-possible-to-display-a-wpf-window-without-an-icon-in-the-title-bar)